# Sum of a substring sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, substring

I have a series of numbers; I want to create a formula/algorithm to generate an integer number so that each number series is unique and higher than the previous one.

The number series are the following.

```
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.4
.....
1.1.z

1.2.1
1.3.1
1.4.1
.....
1.z.1

1.1.1
2.1.1
3.1.1
4.1.1
.....
z.1.1

  .
  .
  .
```

The series first number sequence starts with `1.1.1` and the maximum number of this sequence is `1.1.z`
The second series starts with `1.2.1` and the maximum number of this sequence is `1.2.z` and so on

Each of the series first number is bigger than the previous series last number, which ends with `z`. For example, `1.2.1` is bugger than `1.1.z`, even for one point.

For the simplicity of the number sequence, the maximum number of each number could be 1000, but `z` is bigger than 1000.

I've tried to assign a base number in the number sequence like

```
1.1.1 => (300+1)+(200+1)+(100+1) => 603
```

But this solution is not working with the following sequence, not even with `z`

```
3.2.1 => (300+3)+(200+2)+(100+1) => 606
4.1.1 => (300+4)+(200+1)+(100+1) => 606
```

Which are the same number but the are different is reality.

Any suggestions would be helpfull. Thanks

Comment: Not very clear quive anexple of the output. what have you try ? : 1/ "the maximum number of each number could be 1000":  Do you really want to generate 1_000_000_000 items? "z is bigger than 1000": so what is really z? how it is related to numbers ?

Comment: z is just a bigger number, you could say it is 1001 as 1000 is the last series of number before z

Answer (score 4):

You can think of this problem like creating a base-z number. Given a `z` and your places (from right to left), the integer will be `n * (z+1) ** place`

So given a z of 5:  `0.0.1` will correspond to `1`, `0.0.2` is `2`. When you get to z you get `0.1.0`, which is 6, etc.

```
def to_int(s, z):
    z = z + 1
    digits = map(int, reversed(s.split('.')))
    return sum(n * (z ** place) for place, n in enumerate(digits))


l = [
    '0.0.0',
    '0.0.1',
    '1.1.1',
    '1.1.2',
    '1.1.3',
    '1.1.4',
    '1.1.5',
    '1.2.1',
    '1.3.1',
    '1.4.1',
    '1.1.1',
    '2.1.1',
    '3.1.1',
    '4.1.1'
]

print([to_int(s, 5) for s in l])   
# [0, 1, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 55, 61, 43, 79, 115, 151]
```

If a `z` of `1000` is allowed, the integers will get big quickly, because numbers `0-1000` are encoded in `0.0.0` to `0.0.1000` making `0.1.0` equal `1001` and `1.0.0` equal `1002001`

Comment: this gives a problem if you have a series with the value "1.15.1" that will be higer than "4.1.1"

Comment: Thanks @BendikKnapstad. I was reversing the string, which made `1000` into `0001`. If you want to use a number like `1.15.1` you need to set `z` to 15, then `1.15.1` will be `497` and `4.1.1` will be `1041`.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark for your answer, however, this solution is not working for most of the cases like ``1.1.512`` and ``1.2.1`` where output is ``545`` and ``49`` which is a break of sequence. also ``z`` is not working.

Comment: @AbdulAwal you need to set `z` appropriately. If you call `to_int('1.2.1', 5)` you will get `49`, but it doesn't make sense to also call `to_int('1.1.512', 5)` because passing in `5` as `z` when your numbers go up to 512 won't work. You need to pass in `z` that is as large as your largest numbers.  For example: `to_int('1.2.1', 512), to_int('1.1.512', 512)` produces `(264196, 264194)`

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I am getting an exception when there is any ``z``  value present because the map function is allowed only the ``int`` value. For example, ``1.1.z``. Anything I missed?